# Invalid syntax in "while loop"

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

So, I'm doing a project for school in python that converts normal numbers to binary and I've stopped here because of a "while loop" error, here's the code:

```
number = float(input("What's your number: "))
binary = 0
is_integer = True
binary_lenght = len(int(binary)

while number < 0:
  number = number/2
  is_integer = (number).is_integer()
  binary_lenght = len(binary)
  if is_integer == True:
    binary = binary + "0"
    binary = float(binary)
```

and I get

```
  File "main.py", line 6
    while number < 0:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have missing closing parenthesis on previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis on line `binary_lenght = len(int(binary)`

Here is the code after fix.

```py
number = float(input("What's your number: "))
binary = 0
is_integer = True
binary_lenght = len(int(binary))

while number < 0:
  number = number/2
  is_integer = (number).is_integer()
  binary_lenght = len(binary)
  if is_integer == True:
    binary = binary + "0"
    binary = float(binary)
```